# Why ASP.net Ajax Control toolkit control has runat="server" tag?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When we are using ASP.net server control toolkit in ASP.NET application.

Ajax toolkit control validates at **client side** then why **runat="server"** attribute for their controls.

Comment: What do you mean by "validates at client side"? They are server side controls and therefore they require runat="server"

Comment: It validates at browser rather than server @OscarSiauw

Comment: what do you mean by "validate"? They are server side controls, which then get rendered into their client-side representation of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runat="server"` means that your markup element will be a server-side control. This means that their `ID` will represent an object generated on server-side. As a result, your control will be created on server-side and, if event handlers are associated to it, then they will run. This does not mean that your control will solely run on the server, as the thing generated on server-side will be sent to the browser. This not stop them from being validated on client-side. `runat` is a bit misleading, its name suggests that the element will run on the server, but in fact it means it will be a server-side control, which, of course can have client-side events at the end of the day.